# Can't run Rake commands any more, hpricot_scan.bundle no suitable image found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard, rake

Since I migrated to Snow Leopard I can't run any Rake command from the command line.

e.g if I try to run `rake stats` I get:

```
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.1/lib/hpricot_scan.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.1/lib/hpricot_scan.bundle: no matching architecture in universal wrapper - /Users/xxx/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.1/lib/hpricot_scan.bundle
/Users/xxx/Projects/MyProject/Rakefile:10
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the gem was built before you upgraded, you will probably have to rebuild it (32-bit then, 64-bit now). As I haven't upgraded, I don't know from experience, but you can have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367380/snow-leopard-64-bit-ruby-gem-problem) as an example. Another good bet is to have a look at some of the [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gem+snow+leopard) for gems on snow leopard. Good luck.